# Artifactory create conan channels

Tags: artifactory, conan

I have an artifactory server with a connan repository.
Currently I have a CI system that pushes to a single conan channel `acme/stable`

```
conan upload base64/1.0.0-2@acme/stable
```

How would you create a second channel and restrict artifactory permissions so not all users could write to the stable channel?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new artifactory permission that can write to the `conan-local` repo

Remove the `Include Pattern` `**`
Create an `Exclude Pattern` that matches `acme/**/**/stable/**`

Now users will be able to upload their own test packages, but not be able to overwrite the stable channel.

```
conan upload base64/1.0.0-2@acme/stable -r artifactory
```

[image]